# Is Jetty ever used for production deployment?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, jetty

Why would it be preferred over Tomcat?

Is your experience with big or little companies?  Internal or external (customer/public facing) systems?

Comment: ...Zimbra uses it, so i guess it is used

Comment: Alot of applications use it as an embedded web server. However it is usually used as a management/supporting role for an application which is not a web server in itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could look at [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/powered/) listing products that use Jetty.

One example you might (unknowingly) be familiar with is that the Eclipse IDE's help system uses Jetty.

Comment: A more current link to the page of Jetty-using companies:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/powered/powered.html

Answer (score 14):

Google App Engine for Java (GAE/J) uses Jetty as servlet container.

Answer (score 5):

We use Jetty for a production environment. Very small and easy to install.

Answer (score 5):

Jetty is in a lot of production environments. It is very easy to install, configure and deploy on. No fluffy management stuff that gets in the way.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen Jetty used for production deployments for lightweight http servers for restful services. For simple servers that relay requests back to a service Jetty is often enough.

Answer (score 3):

It is used quite often in embedded mode. If your server needs extra http component, you can just throw in Jetty, write few servlets, and you're done. Tomcat isn't/wasn't as good for embedding as Jetty is.